# Should i use solr's Data Import Handler or send data from asp.net mvc application using solrnet to solr?

Tags: asp.net, solr, asp.net-mvc-5, solrnet, dih

I have a situation where i want events from 2 databases in my asp.net mvc 5 application while searching. Which is the best way-
1) solr's data import handler
2) or send data for indexing through my application using solrnet.
please suggest me. If possible provide code also.

Answer (score 1):

Send data from your application. That is far more flexible and easier to adjust, as well as you can update any information as soon as it changes, instead of having to pull it from the database in regular intervals.

I recommend having a message queue actually send the update to Solr, so that you don't have to contact Solr directly in your frontend controller, but instead request the job / message queue to perform the update on your behalf. It's far easier to scale out and doesn't drag down your whole application if the updates against Solr drags out.

That being said, you'll also have to have a decent way to reindex your content, either through submitting all documents manually again, or by using the data import handler to pull the initial content.

Comment: how i can add new data to solr from code when database updates.

Comment: You call the appropriate method on a SolrNet client with the document you've just inserted into your database; exactly how you do this depends on your platform, libraries and implementation.

Comment: using solrnet is there any way to get total records from solr instead of this => var lstMain = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("*:*")).Count();

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments. As far as I can see from the docs, there's a .Count property that returns the total number of documents in the query. See 'pagination' in the docs for how to limit the number of documents returned (you usually want to retrieve 0 documents if you're only doing counting).